# Editing code on the iPad and deploying it to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ipad, heroku

Does anybody know an ios ipad app that would allow me to edit a github hosted rails project and deploy it on Heroku?

The reason I'm asking is that I'm an independent Web developer and I like to go on vacation bringing only my iPad. But I want to make sure that if there's a quick bug fix that needs to be done, I can safely do it from my ipad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally after almost 3 years it seems like there is finally a solution with the recent release of [Heroku Dropbox Sync](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/11/19/announcing_beta_dropbox_sync).

Using [Textastic](http://www.textasticapp.com/) or any other iPad code editor app that supports syncing with Dropbox, I can make local changes to the code on my ipad, sync it to Dropbox and use the Heroku Dashboard web page to initiate a deploy on Heroku.

Answer (score 5):

I have been looking into various options, This is what I have found so far:

- Ipad Apps

Hopefully [worqshop](http://worqshop.com/) will reintroduce the plugin.

The developer of textastic is working on [git support](http://feedback.textasticapp.com/topic/7628-support-for-version-control-systems-svn-git-etc/#comment_112950)

- Cloud IDE's

Cloud9 is working on ipad support. I think others are as well.

- Continuos deployment

Add a "deploy on green" task to a CI server such as Jenkins.

- Use an ipad ssh client to ssh into a workstation or server and deploy from there.

Pro: future proof, not reliant on a 3rd party app that may drop support for a needed feature.

Con: requires a workstation or server

- [Codeship](https://www.codeship.io/) integrates with github and heroku and can deploy to heroku.

Comment: Seems to be just what I'm looking for. Thanks for suggesting it, I will give it a try!

Comment: They have dropped support for Heroku in version 2.0 so I'm back to square one. Any other alternatives?

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer! I made some pressure on the creator of Worqshop and he might reintroduce the feature soon. I'll mark your answer as solved again if he does so. The other options seem rather complicated since I really just want to use the ipad as an emergency tool to make urgent bug fixes when I'm on vacation or out for the week-end.

Comment: It would be great if the feature was added to version 2! I wonder if the author dropped the feature because it required he maintain a server. If that is the case, maybe, charging a small fee or similar would make it more viable.

Comment: I just stumbled upon another possible option called codeship, I will add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some kind of interim box I'm afraid - somewhere that you could ssh into from the ipad and then deploy/develop from there to Heroku.

Take a read of http://yieldthought.com/post/12239282034/swapped-my-macbook-for-an-ipad - not specifically for Rails development but the principle reamins the same.

The other option is http://c9.io/ but I've not tried but it may be an option.

Comment: I didn't know about cloud9, that's an ambitious project! But a little pricy if that's not something I'm going to use on a regular basis. Right now, I think my best hope is that Textastic adds git support in an eventual release : http://feedback.textasticapp.com/topic/7628-support-for-version-control-systems-svn-git-etc/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Nitrous.io.

IDE runs on your browser.

One click install applications.

Terminal and SSH access.

Use a text editor app on the ipad that allows you to sftp.